# File IO exhausting System Memory on a Windows 7 64bit system

Tags: windows

I am writting a software like emule,  which work right on my Windows XP 32bit. However, some users report to me that while downloading big files( large than 2GB or more) on Win7 64 bit,  the system memory exhatsted,  especially with the Avast!(anti-virus software) running together. I use process monitor to watch the behavior of avast!,  found that, avast continuesly read the downloading files. (As the software pre-allocate file space,  download and write to a fix-sized file may like virus)

This situation are similar as the following articles describe,  that means the FileSystem Cache exhaust the physical memory.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2009/02/06/microsoft-windows-dynamic-cache-service.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2007/11/27/too-much-cache.aspx

I have tried some methods,  one is use FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING flag with CreateFile API to read and write,  this avoid using System File cache,  and The system file cache stop grow even if the Avast! still scaning the downloading files.

Through i resolved the problem,  i still don't understand why Avast! doesnot exhaust memory any more while i use NO_BUFFERING mode to read and write file.

Comment: The Filesystem cache isn't likely to exhaust physical memory, ever. The reason being that if ever there isn't enough physical memory left, pages in the FS cache are the first to be discarded. More likely, Avast! is _locking_ too large amounts of memory (and, possibly, locking pages from the filesystem cache). Being a rootkit, Avast! isn't subject to the usual working set quotas, so it's able to do that kind of thing. Which doesn't mean that it does so in a bug-free manner...

Comment: I guess u hasn't read the msdn article i post. In Win32,  Filesystem cache cost at most 1GB,  but in Win64.  I have tried in my demo in win64, read write a file large than 4GB,   the memory usuage cost 2gb,  as i only installed 4gb ram,  the memory alomost exhausted.

Comment: Our cumstomer reported while download a 4GB file,  their  8 gb ram will exhausted,  after i replace the file IO method from bufferint to non-buffering ,  this memory exhaust doesnot happen any more

Comment: I have read that article, but it's only of mild interest (even though it's on MSDN, it's mostly allegoric). Processes are paged in and out (or moved to standby) all the time, this doesn't mean much. A process that isn't active _should_ be paged out. It's the fact that Avast! is touching (and presumably locking) the pages in the cache over and over again all the time, not so much the fact that the pages are in the cache. In a healthy environment (i.e. no commercial antivirus malware interfering), there is no issue with the whole RAM being filled by caches. In fact, RAM _should_ be filled at...

Comment: ... at all times, since there is nothing worse than unused RAM. Contrary to popular belief, free RAM is not a good thing. Free RAM means you've spent too much money, since you could as well have bought less. Pages being moved to standby or being discarded (both from process working sets and the FS cache) is a normal thing to happen, it's happening hundreds of times every second. If the FS cache takes up the by far greatest part of physical pages, the likelihood of a FS page being discarded is much higher than of a process page, so this is self-throttling. Except... if you (Avast) interfere.

Comment: but,  when the ram is almost depleted,  the system act very very slow,   I guess large scale page in page out cause system slow